# Handling dash callback of an input inside the multi Tab app

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a multi tab dash application based on the reference code from https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/examples/graphs-in-tabs/#sourceCode

My requirement is to have the Button inside the Histogram Tab page instead on the Main page. I have modified the reference code to achieve this. Below is the modified code.

Commented out from app.layout and Moved dbc.Button inside the Tab as the first column (Callback modification):

```
@app.callback(
    Output("tab-content", "children"),
    [Input("tabs", "active_tab"), Input("store", "data")],
)
def render_tab_content(active_tab, data):
    """
    This callback takes the 'active_tab' property as input, as well as the
    stored graphs, and renders the tab content depending on what the value of
    'active_tab' is.
    """
    if active_tab and data is not None:
        if active_tab == "scatter":
            return dcc.Graph(figure=data["scatter"])
        elif active_tab == "histogram":
                return dbc.Row(
                    [
                 #Modified to add the Button inside the Tab
                        dbc.Col(dbc.Button(
                        "Regenerate graphs",
                        color="primary",
                        block=True,
                        id="iButton",
                        className="mb-3",
                        ), width=4
                    ),
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=data["hist_1"]), width=4),
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=data["hist_2"]), width=4),
                ]
            )
    return "No tab selected"
```

2nd change is as below, updated the iButton as input in the callback:

```
@app.callback(Output("store", "data"), [Input("iButton", "n_clicks")])
def generate_graphs(n):
```

With this change, exception is raised when the application is run

```
ID not found in layout

Attempting to connect a callback Input item to component:
  "iButton"
but no components with that id exist in the layout.
```

I am not sure how to handle the Button behaviour when inside the Tab.

Answer (score 7):

When dash first evaluates the app it tries to resolve the callback inputs using the layout components in the `app.layout`. The Button cannot be found because it is added later inside your callback so dash doesn't know about it just yet.

What I would recommend is restructuring the layout and callbacks a little bit, so that each component is known from the beginning.

#### Layout

Define every component of the layout beforehand. Define each `Div` but don't show both of them at the start

```
app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.H1("Dynamically rendered tab content"),
        html.Hr(),
        dbc.Tabs(
            [
                dbc.Tab(label = "Scatter", tab_id = "scatter"),
                dbc.Tab(label = "Histograms", tab_id = "histogram"),
            ],
            id = "tabs",
            active_tab = "scatter",
        ),
        html.Div(id = "hist-tab", className = "p-4", children = [
            dbc.Row(
                [
                    # Modified to add the Button inside the Tab
                    dbc.Col(dbc.Button(
                        "Regenerate graphs",
                        color = "primary",
                        block = True,
                        id = "iButton",
                        className = "mb-3",
                    ), width = 4
                    ),
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'hist-1', figure = {}), width = 4),
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'hist-2', figure = {}), width = 4)
                ]
            )
        ]),
        html.Div(id = "scatter-tab", className = "p-4", children = [
            dcc.Graph(figure = {}, id = 'scatter-plot')
        ], style = {'display': 'none'}),
    ])
```

Setting the `Div` style to `{'display': 'block'}` will show the Div, setting it to `{'display': 'none'}` will hide it for now.

#### Callbacks

The first callback listening to the `Tab` will be in charge of making the `Div`s vizible and invizble:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("hist-tab", "style"), Output("scatter-tab", "style")],
    [Input("tabs", "active_tab")],
)
def render_tab_content(active_tab):
    """
    This callback takes the 'active_tab' property as input, as well as the
    stored graphs, and renders the tab content depending on what the value of
    'active_tab' is.
    """
    on = {'display': 'block'}
    off = {'display': 'none'}
    if active_tab is not None:
        if active_tab == "scatter":
            return off, on
        elif active_tab == "histogram":
            return on, off
    return "No tab selected"
```

Since every component exists at every point, the second callback can directly write the data to the `Figure`s

```
@app.callback([Output("hist-1", "figure"), Output("hist-2", "figure"), Output("scatter-plot", "figure")],
              [Input("iButton", "n_clicks")])
def generate_graphs(n):
    """
    This callback generates three simple graphs from random data.
    """
    if not n:
        # generate empty graphs when app loads
        return {}, {}, {}

    # simulate expensive graph generation process
    time.sleep(2)

    # generate 100 multivariate normal samples
    data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]], 100)

    scatter = go.Figure(
        data = [go.Scatter(x = data[:, 0], y = data[:, 1], mode = "markers")]
    )
    hist_1 = go.Figure(data = [go.Histogram(x = data[:, 0])])
    hist_2 = go.Figure(data = [go.Histogram(x = data[:, 1])])

    # save figures in a dictionary for sending to the dcc.Store
    return hist_1, hist_2, scatter
```

Comment: Just an update that active_tab is now called value as of Dash 2.0 https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tabs#tabs-properties